# TyperError: expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, html, sql, oracle

My code parses data out of an HTML table and then exports it to my Oracle Database. For some reason when running the code on a table, I **sometimes** receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Code\successfullest_html_code.py", line 122, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

On most tables, my code works perfectly, and for the ones that produce this error I've just been entering by hand.. but now these errors are occurring more frequently. I would just like to know why this happens only on some tables and not on others when they all appear identical.

I've read this error gets produced when you try to run something other than a string (or bytes object) thru a command. But these tables are all pretty much identical so it confuses me why this error gets produced sometimes.

Here's my code; though you can disregard most of it, the error occurs on the line `cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import email
import cx_Oracle

dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("sole.nefsc.noaa.gov", "1526", "sole")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="username", password="password$", dsn=dsnStr)

def celltext(cell):
    '''    
        textlist=[]
        for br in cell.findAll('br'):
            next = br.nextSibling
            if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
                continue
            next2 = next.nextSibling
            if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':
                text = str(next).strip()
                if text:
                    textlist.append(next)
        return (textlist)
    '''
    textlist=[]
    y = cell.find('span')
    for a in y.childGenerator(): 
        if isinstance(a, NavigableString):
            textlist.append(str(a))
    return (textlist)

path = 'Z:\\bins_html_yes'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path,'r') as w:
            html=w.read()
        #html=open(file_path,'r').read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
            table = soup.find_all('table')[1] # Grab the second table

df_Quota = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b')
            email = f.read()
            dates = pattern.findall(email)
            if dates:
                export_year = (''.join(dates))
                print("export_year:", export_year)

for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        if columns[0].get_text().strip()!='ID':# skip header
            #print("First Column:", columns[0].get_text().strip())
            Quota = celltext(columns[1]) 
            Weight =  celltext(columns[2])
            price =  celltext(columns[3])

            Nrows= max([len(Quota),len(Weight),len(price)]) #get the max number of rows

            IDList = [columns[0].get_text()] * Nrows
            DateList = [columns[4].get_text()] * Nrows

            if price[0].strip()=='Package':
                 price = [columns[3].get_text()] * Nrows

            if len(Quota)<len(Weight):#if Quota has less itmes extend with NaN
               lstnans= [np.nan]*(len(Weight)-len(Quota))
               Quota.extend(lstnans)

            if len(price) < len(Quota): #if price column has less items than quota column,
                val = [columns[3].get_text()] * (len(Quota)-len(price)) #extend with 
                price.extend(val)                                       #whatever is in
                                                                        #price column

            #if len(DateList) > len(Quota): #if DateList is longer than Quota, 
                #print("it's longer than")
                #value = [columns[4].get_text()] * (len(DateList)-len(Quota))
                #DateList = value * Nrows

            if len(Quota) < len(DateList): #if Quota is less than DateList (due to gap),
                stu = [columns[1].get_text()] * (len(DateList)-len(Quota)) #extend with what exists
                #stu = [np.nan]*(len(DateList)-len(Quota)) #extend with NaN
                Quota.extend(stu)

            if len(Weight) < len(DateList):
                dru = [columns[2].get_text()] * (len(DateList)-len(Weight)) #extend with what exists
                #dru = [np.nan]*(len(DateList)-len(Weight)) #extend with Nan
                Weight.extend(dru)

            FinalDataframe = pd.DataFrame(
            {
            'ID':IDList,    
            'AvailableQuota': Quota,
            'LiveWeightPounds': Weight,
            'price':price,
            'DatePosted':DateList
            })
            #print("ID:", IDList)
            #print("Price:", price)

            df_Quota = df_Quota.append(FinalDataframe, ignore_index=True)
            #df_Q = df_Quota['DatePosted'].iloc[0] #capture only most recent
            #df_Quota = df_Quota[df_Quota['DatePosted'] == df_Q] #date's data 
    except IndexError:
        continue

df_Quota['year'] = export_year

print ("Dataframe is:", df_Quota)

cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df_Quota.values]
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO FISHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, advertised_price, year_posted, sector_name, ask)" "VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, 'NEFS 2', '1')")
cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
con.commit() #commit to database

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Here's a table that it successfully exports:

[image]

And here's a table that it fails on:

[image]

Here is a printout of the DataFrame (the `\n`s don't actually mess up the export at all):

```
Dataframe is:       AvailableQuota DatePosted        ID LiveWeightPounds    price  year
0         White Hake   \n4/15\n   \n002\n           50,000    $0.10  2015
1            GOM COD   \n3/23\n  \n1493\n            3,600    $0.60  2015
2         \nGreysole   \n3/23\n  \n1493\n            \n350  \n$1.25  2015
3            GBE COD   \n3/20\n  \n1878\n            1,113    $0.60  2015
4               Dabs   \n3/18\n  \n1043\n            3,000    $0.50  2015
5         \nGreysole   \n3/18\n  \n1043\n            \n700   \n$.85  2015
6           GOM HADD   \n3/13\n   \n011\n              790    $0.50  2015
7               Dabs   \n3/13\n   \n370\n            2,100     $.60  2015
8         \nGreySole   \n3/13\n   \n370\n          \n4,700   \n$.85  2015
9            GOM COD   \n3/13\n  \n1734\n            1,900    $0.90  2015
10        \nGOM HADD   \n3/13\n  \n1734\n          \n1,000  \n$1.00  2015
11        \nGreysole   \n3/13\n  \n1734\n          \n3,000  \n$1.50  2015
12            \nDabs   \n3/13\n  \n1734\n          \n2,700  \n$1.00  2015
13           GBW Cod   \n3/13\n   \n816\n           12,000    $0.40  2015
14            \nDabs   \n3/13\n   \n816\n          \n2,000  \n$0.60  2015
15        \nGreysole   \n3/13\n   \n816\n          \n2,000  \n$0.90  2015
16           GOM COD   \n3/13\n   \n373\n              300    $0.90  2015
17  \nGOM YellowTail   \n3/13\n   \n373\n          \n3,300  \n$0.20  2015
18        \nGOM Hadd   \n3/13\n   \n373\n          \n1,000  \n$0.50  2015
19          GOM Hadd   \n3/11\n   \n001\n             2500    $0.40  2015
20          GOM HADD    \n3/9\n   \n187\n            1,100    $0.50  2015
21       \nGreysole     \n3/9\n   \n187\n            \n900  \n$0.85  2015
22            \nDabs    \n3/9\n   \n187\n            \n450  \n$0.50  2015
23           GOM COD    \n3/5\n   \n255\n              500    $0.40  2015
24        \nGOM Hadd    \n3/5\n   \n255\n          \n1,000  \n$0.40  2015
25  \nGOM Yellowtail    \n3/5\n   \n255\n          \n3,000  \n$0.20  2015
26          Gom Hadd   \n2/12\n   \n485\n            5,800    $0.40  2015
27  \nGom Yellowtail   \n2/12\n   \n485\n           \n1100  \n$0.20  2015
28          GOM HADD   \n1/26\n   \n314\n              439    $1.50  2015
29  \nGOM Yellowtail   \n1/26\n   \n314\n          \n2,274  \n$0.25  2015
30          GOM HADD   \n1/26\n  \n1610\n            2,950    $0.70  2015
31               NaN   \n1/26\n  \n1610\n            \n500       \n  2015
32               NaN   \n1/26\n  \n1610\n          \n2,550  \n$0.25  2015
33    GOM Yellowtail   \n1/23\n   \n347\n            4,780    $0.25  2015
34    GOM Yellowtail   \n1/23\n   \n802\n            2,141    $0.25  2015
35              POLL   \n12/8\n  \n310B\n            65234    $0.01  2015
36             \nRED   \n12/8\n  \n310B\n          \n76610  \n$0.01  2015
37          \nSNE BB   \n12/8\n  \n310B\n           \n2121  \n$0.30  2015
38          \nGOM BB   \n12/8\n  \n310B\n           \n7285  \n$0.05  2015
39            GOM BB   \n5/29\n   \n588\n             9989    $0.10  2015
40          \nGOM YT   \n5/29\n   \n588\n           \n6172  \n$0.25  2015
41            \nPOLL   \n5/29\n   \n588\n          \n10314  \n$0.01  2015
42         \nREDFISH   \n5/29\n   \n588\n           \n2705  \n$0.01  2015
```

And here is a printout of `(exported_data)`:

```
[('White Hake', '\n4/15\n', '\n002\n', '50,000', '$0.10', '2015'), ('GOM COD', '\n3/23\n', '\n1493\n', '3,600', '$0.60', '2015'), ('\nGreysole', '\n3/23\n', '\n1493\n', '\n350', '\n$1.25', '2015'), ('GBE COD', '\n3/20\n', '\n1878\n', '1,113', '$0.60', '2015'), ('Dabs', '\n3/18\n', '\n1043\n', '3,000', '$0.50', '2015'), ('\nGreysole', '\n3/18\n', '\n1043\n', '\n700', '\n$.85', '2015'), ('GOM HADD', '\n3/13\n', '\n011\n', '790', '$0.50', '2015'), ('Dabs', '\n3/13\n', '\n370\n', '2,100', '$.60', '2015'), ('\nGreySole', '\n3/13\n', '\n370\n', '\n4,700', '\n$.85', '2015'), ('GOM COD', '\n3/13\n', '\n1734\n', '1,900', '$0.90', '2015'), ('\nGOM HADD', '\n3/13\n', '\n1734\n', '\n1,000', '\n$1.00', '2015'), ('\nGreysole', '\n3/13\n', '\n1734\n', '\n3,000', '\n$1.50', '2015'), ('\nDabs', '\n3/13\n', '\n1734\n', '\n2,700', '\n$1.00', '2015'), ('GBW Cod', '\n3/13\n', '\n816\n', '12,000', '$0.40', '2015'), ('\nDabs', '\n3/13\n', '\n816\n', '\n2,000', '\n$0.60', '2015'), ('\nGreysole', '\n3/13\n', '\n816\n', '\n2,000', '\n$0.90', '2015'), ('GOM COD', '\n3/13\n', '\n373\n', '300', '$0.90', '2015'), ('\nGOM YellowTail', '\n3/13\n', '\n373\n', '\n3,300', '\n$0.20', '2015'), ('\nGOM Hadd', '\n3/13\n', '\n373\n', '\n1,000', '\n$0.50', '2015'), ('GOM Hadd', '\n3/11\n', '\n001\n', '2500', '$0.40', '2015'), ('GOM HADD', '\n3/9\n', '\n187\n', '1,100', '$0.50', '2015'), ('\nGreysole ', '\n3/9\n', '\n187\n', '\n900', '\n$0.85', '2015'), ('\nDabs', '\n3/9\n', '\n187\n', '\n450', '\n$0.50', '2015'), ('GOM COD', '\n3/5\n', '\n255\n', '500', '$0.40', '2015'), ('\nGOM Hadd', '\n3/5\n', '\n255\n', '\n1,000', '\n$0.40', '2015'), ('\nGOM Yellowtail', '\n3/5\n', '\n255\n', '\n3,000', '\n$0.20', '2015'), ('Gom Hadd', '\n2/12\n', '\n485\n', '5,800', '$0.40', '2015'), ('\nGom Yellowtail', '\n2/12\n', '\n485\n', '\n1100', '\n$0.20', '2015'), ('GOM HADD', '\n1/26\n', '\n314\n', '439', '$1.50', '2015'), ('\nGOM Yellowtail', '\n1/26\n', '\n314\n', '\n2,274', '\n$0.25', '2015'), ('GOM HADD', '\n1/26\n', '\n1610\n', '2,950', '$0.70', '2015'), (nan, '\n1/26\n', '\n1610\n', '\n500', '\n', '2015'), (nan, '\n1/26\n', '\n1610\n', '\n2,550', '\n$0.25', '2015'), ('GOM Yellowtail', '\n1/23\n', '\n347\n', '4,780', '$0.25', '2015'), ('GOM Yellowtail', '\n1/23\n', '\n802\n', '2,141', '$0.25', '2015'), ('POLL', '\n12/8\n', '\n310B\n', '65234', '$0.01', '2015'), ('\nRED', '\n12/8\n', '\n310B\n', '\n76610', '\n$0.01', '2015'), ('\nSNE BB', '\n12/8\n', '\n310B\n', '\n2121', '\n$0.30', '2015'), ('\nGOM BB', '\n12/8\n', '\n310B\n', '\n7285', '\n$0.05', '2015'), ('GOM BB', '\n5/29\n', '\n588\n', '9989', '$0.10', '2015'), ('\nGOM YT', '\n5/29\n', '\n588\n', '\n6172', '\n$0.25', '2015'), ('\nPOLL', '\n5/29\n', '\n588\n', '\n10314', '\n$0.01', '2015'), ('\nREDFISH', '\n5/29\n', '\n588\n', '\n2705', '\n$0.01', '2015')]
```

Among other things, it really confuses me why the error occurs on that line of all places... the `cursor.executemany()` is just supposed carry out the SQL query from the lines above, right? It works for some tables but fails on others and I really don't know why. Any help explaining and solving this is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Also, I would suggest putting a debugging output on `exported_data` right before the call. I suspect one of the tuples in your list is malformed.

Comment: Sorry please forgive me for being a noob but what is a stack trace? And I've never actually used a debugger...

Comment: when it says `TypeError: expecting string or bytes object` it is accompanied by a bunch of other text. Post the entire set (although I would replace any personal data with placeholder values like `user` and `company`)

Comment: The full error has been added

Comment: Directly before the statement giving an error, do a `print(exported_data)` and post the results it gets right before the crash.

Comment: It's been done.

Comment: see line 31/32, which have `NaN` in them? That's very likely to be the issue.

Comment: Several things: 1) that honestly makes sense that a `NaN` would cause the error... but why are `NaN`s appearing where actual fish stocks should be appearing? With ID 1610 there should be Greysole and GOM Yellowtail, why `NaN`s then? And 2) why should `NaN`s cause the export fail? My Oracle is set to allow `Null` in a cell so shouldn't it accept a `NaN` result?

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(Quota)<len(Weight):  #if Quota has less itmes extend with NaN
    lstnans= [np.nan]*(len(Weight)-len(Quota))
    Quota.extend(lstnans)
```

You're intentionally adding `nan`s to your list to cover up some parsing error. The root cause is in building `Quota`.

And to answer your question:

> why should NaNs cause the export fail? My Oracle is set to allow Null in a cell so shouldn't it accept a NaN result?

```
>>> float('NaN') == None
False
```

`nan` is not `None`/`Null`

Comment: Ok so `NaN`s cause it to fail since `NaN` isn't equal to `Null`. Is there a way around that? Can I replace those `NaN`s with something that will fit in the Oracle table cells?

Comment: @theprowler there is so issue with your parsing of the table that is causing that -> as you mentioned, those fields have values in the original data. You need to figure out why they are failing to parse. You can change it to `None`, but that won't fix the parsing issues.

Comment: Right right right. That makes sense. I have no clue why it decides to fail, I think the creator of the tables each week adds random \n's into the cells that my code captures instead of the string of characters that I want it to capture. It only happens sometimes so I guess I'll have to live with it. Thanks though

Comment: @theprowler the immediate change I would make it adding `.strip()` to all values in the table to remove all the random `\n`